# How to Target SharePoint Announcements to Different Groups of Users From the Same Announcement List in SharePoint 2007

Tags: alert

My organization created a SharePoint Announcement list and subscribed all of the organization's divisions to that announcement list. So, now when you create a new announcement, everyone in the organization gets that announcement.  Is there a way to separate the groups (divisions) so that we can send an announcement only to the divisions that need to see that announcement?